# Leitura de Json com PHP

Tags: php, json

Galera, estou com uma dúvida na leitura do Json com PHP.

O Json é esse:

```
{"message":"Oi Gente","report":[{"0":[{"port":"gsm-2.3","phonenumber":"00000000000","time":"1970-01-08 10:00:26","result":"fail"}]}]},
```

mas não consigo exibir seus valores.

Agradeço desde Já!

Comment: QUal é o valor que queres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz assim:

```
$json = '{"message":"Oi Gente","report":[{"0":[{"port":"gsm-2.3","phonenumber":"00000000000","time":"1970-01-08 10:00:26","result":"fail"}]}]}';
$json_dec = json_decode($json, true);
```

Depois se quiseres por exemplo a `message`:

```
echo $json_dec['message'];
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/dp8wds)

Se quiseres por exmplo o `time` em `report`:

```
echo $json_dec['report'][0][0][0]['time'];
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/d4iPwh)